# val_loss missing in keras logs but correctly printed at the end of epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use the `ModelCheckpoint` callback in keras. However, it keeps saying to me that `val_loss` is not available. I added a print statement in the code of `ModelCheckpoint` to check the content of the `logs` input. You can indeed see that `val_loss` is not present in the dictionary.

The weird thing is that `val_loss` is correctly reported at the end of each epoch and it is present in the `history` object generated by `model.fit`. Clearly I provide validation data (otherwise `val_loss` could not be evaluated at the end of each epoch).

```
...
3/3 - 65s - loss: 0.2053 - **val_loss: 0.1153**
Epoch 2/45
logs={'batch': 0, 'size': 30000, 'loss': 0.20355584}
WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_loss available, skipping.
...
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I'm using Keras version '2.2.4-tf' (called from `tf.keras`)

Comment: I'm not following what you mean. Where are these options?

Comment: Forget my last comment, I was thinking of another thing. ---- So, maybe you are using `keras.checkpoints` instead of `tf.keras.checkpoints`? The only explanation for your problem is a bug.

Comment: Hi @LucaAmerio, can you please provide a minimum reproducible code to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the solution here, even though it is present in `Github`, for the benefit of the `StackOverflow Community`.

The issue was caused by some confusion between `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` and `tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`.

In the first (**pure keras**), the argument `period` controls every how many **epochs** the model is saved. This occurs always **at epoch end** when also the `val_loss` is computed and included in `logs`.

In `tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`, instead, `save_freq` controls every how many **batches** the model is saved. This cause the `callback` to be evaluated in the **middle of an epoch**, where `val_loss` is not available.

***Changing `save_freq` to `epoch` (the default) has  resolved the issue.***

Comment: thanks for the great answer. what if we need to calculate the `val_loss` and `val_accuracy` in the middle of an epoch? that is, we want to evaluate the model according to some number of training steps instead of epochs.